# Search large amount of XML files for specific tag

Tags: javascript, xml, search

Let's say I have 1,000 XML files. I need to perform a search and find the file that contains a particular tag. For example:

```
<id>342ierHWR(543irefjsd</id>
```

The search would need to check all of the files to find that ID. Is this possible with JavaScript and would it take a long time to perform the search? Ideally I'd need to know the file containing that ID in under 5 seconds.

Thanks

Comment: Browser JavaScript or node JavaScript? Browser JavaScript doesn't have access to local resources, and trying to load XML documents (of any size) from 1000 URIs is itself probably going to take more than the specified time limit. Also, consider the size of the XML files - if they are of "notable size", then even local access may hit IO limits pretty fast. It might be worthwhile to consider "offline" (in relation to the XML) shredding or indexing so this query can be answered without actually reading the original XML files.

Comment: A tag (`id`), or a specific value for that tag? Can you preprocess these files, i.e., build an index off-line?

Answer (score 0):

use [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep)

```
grep "<id>342ierHWR(543irefjsd</id>" *.xml
```